# Smartphones and tablets ios/android scroll not working

Tags: css, scroll, scrollbar

I have the following structure:

div1 contains div2 which contains multiple div3 elements

```
div1  {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
max-height: 150px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
min-width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

div2 {
position: relative; 
}

div3 {
padding: 7px 5px;
}
```

It looks like a multiselect.

Why can't I scroll inside div1/div2?
I changed overflow-x from hidden to auto in div1 but still no changes. I added "overflow: auto" to div2, but still no changes. I also tried to set max-height of div2 to 150px (similar to div1), but still not working.

Any idea how can I make the div1/div2 scrollable on IOS devices such as iphones or ipads and also on adroid devices?

**EDIT**

I added:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1280px) {
    .div1 {
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
}
```

The css is applied, but still no difference. The scroll is not working on tablets, android/ios.

Jsfiddle with example: https://jsfiddle.net/ykxf7god/

Comment: Try using `overflow-y:scroll`

Comment: It's working on chrome/safari browsers. But not on mobile devices such as android tablets or ipads. I edited my question.

Comment: Could you post a fiddle or smth?

Comment: funny thing is that the jsfiddle worked: https://jsfiddle.net/ykxf7god/

Comment: It seems that the problem is the parent classes from my page. Thanks for suggesting to use fiddle. I'll debug all the parents, because one of them blocks the scroll in my case.

Comment: Make sure there isn't `overflow:hidden` on any element. `overflow-x:hidden` works of course.

Comment: You're right, that's what I'm searching for. Thanks for your help.